# while iterating through ngfor directive is it possible to split a string and display it in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to split a string while iterating though ngfor directive

this is my code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of packageDetails;let i = index">
    <div  class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ic-customer-packageDiv" >
        <nb-card  class="package_card" [ngClass]="{'ic-customer-freePackageBody':item.packageType=='free','ic-customer-activePkg': item.id == activePackageId,'ic-customer-inactivePkg': item.id != activePackageId}" style="border-radius:unset">
            <nb-card-header class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'ic-customer-cardFreeHeader' : item.packageType=='free','ic-customer-cardHeader' : item.packageType!='free'}">                               
                <p class="ic-customer-packageTitle control-label" [class.ic-customer-freePackage]="item.packageType=='free'">{{item.name}}</p>          
            </nb-card-header>
            <nb-card-body>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group ic-customer-packagePriceDiv">
                        <p class="ic-customer-packagePrice" *ngIf=" item.packageType != 'free'">$ {{item.cost}}/ YEAR</p>
                        <p class="ic-customer-packagePrice" *ngIf=" item.packageType == 'free'" [class.ic-customer-freePackage]="item.packageType=='free'">FREE!!!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <ng-template *ngFor="let descr of item.description | split">
                         <p class="ic-customer-packageDescription" [class.ic-customer-freePackage]="item.packageType=='free'">{{descr}}</p>
                      </ng-template>
                   </div>
```

the pipe file code is

```
import { Pipe,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name:'split'
})

export class splitPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) {
        console.log(value.split('\n'));
        return value.split('\n');
    }
}
```

but it displays nothing in the html file.i can't find any problems in this codes

Comment: Do you see the `console.log`message? Does the `ngFor` work as expected without the pipe? also be aware that `split` returns an array, so I don't know how the `{{}}` string interpolation will work with that.

Comment: debug the pipe code? BTW, use strong typing for your pipe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer.It just because of using ng-template.In the above code i am simply defining a template but not using yet.so i replaced ng-template with ng-container,now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use a pipe, in your second *ngFor call a function in your component ts file to get the split.

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let descr of splitDescription(item.description)">
       <p class="ic-customer-packageDescription" [class.ic-customer-
               freePackage]="item.packageType=='free'">{{descr}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

In typescript file:

```
splitDescription(theString: string) {
     return value.split('\n');
}
```

Comment: any reason for not using a pipe?

Comment: not really, just my preference. I've found that sometimes trying to use *ngFor doesn't work when trying to cycle through a list that was accessed right there in the html and by instead calling a function that returns the list fixes the issue